# Why is my entered data not stored in Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
public List<TextBox> _textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

protected void btmSubmit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dbDataItem();
}
public void dbDataItem()
{
    dc.cnn.Open();
    _textBoxes = getTextBox();
    //foreach (TextBox text in _textBoxes)
    //{
    //    _textBoxes.Add(text.Text.Trim());
    //    //StoreValue(text.Text);
    //}
    foreach (TextBox textBox in _textBoxes)
    {
        //TextBox txt = new TextBox();

        //txt.ID = Panel2.FindControl("textBox").ToString();
        string value = textBox.Text;

        string query = "select name from DataItem where name = '" + value + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, dc.cnn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);            
        int count = dt.Rows.Count;


        if (count == 0)
        {
            int i = MaxCode1();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into DataItem (code,name) values (@code,@name)", dc.cnn);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", i);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", value);
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            da2.Fill(dt2);
            dc.cnn.Close();
        }
        else
        {

            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('This DataItem already exist in database');</script>");

        }
    }

    dc.cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do you think that the title is sufficient to describe your problem?

Comment: What are you doing with the `DataAdapter` and `DataTable`? Why don't you just `ExecuteNonQuery()` the `SqlCommand`?

Comment: Any exception or error message?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` to execute an INSERT command is not correct. The Fill method is used to retrieve record from the database using a SELECT statement. In your code the INSERT statement is passed as the SelectCommand of the adapter and it is executed when you call Fill so the record is added to your **database table**. But there is no return value in your **DataTable code object** because the SelectCommand used by the Fill method has no SELECT statement assigned to it.

You need to split the two actions, first ExecuteNonQuery on the INSERT statement, then create the adapter with the correct SELECT statement

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into DataItem (code,name) values (@code,@name)", dc.cnn);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", i);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", value);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM DataItem");
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
da2.Fill(dt2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't run cmd2.

After setting Parameters, run it like this :

```
cm2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

So, your code looks like this :

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into DataItem (code,name) values (@code,@name)", dc.cnn);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", i);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", value);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
dc.cnn.Close();
```

Comment: thnQ so much sir..........I got the solution.....